# coldfusion struct syntax and query data

Tags: coldfusion, struct

I’ve mostly only used coldfusion for queries before never needed structs or any object notation until now. The server I am working on doesn’t have debugging turned on just a “500- internal server error.” so I am unable to see why my code is not working and sadly I do not have the ability to turn debugging on.

By trial and error with commenting blocks out I’ve noticed the errors are occurring in my struct line, and adding the struct to my array. From what I’ve read of the CF documentation I do not see any syntax errors but any help would be much appreciated as to if I have any bad logic or what could be wrong.

```
 <cfset dataArray = []>
 <cfset i = 0>
 <cfloop query="getMembers">
        <cfquery name="getmaps" datasource=“a" dbtype="odbc">
        SELECT       member_id, mlong, mlat
        FROM         maps 
        WHERE       member_id = '#getMembers.MemberID#'
        </cfquery>
        <cfif getmaps.recordcount eq 1>
            <!--- temp structure to insert into array --->
            <cfset dataTemp = {
                memberID = getMemebers.memberID, 
                name = getMemebers.MemberName, 
                long = getmaps.mlong, 
                lat = getmaps.mlat 
            }>
            <cfset dataArray[i] = dataTemp>
            <cfset i++>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Well, you have typos in the names of your struct key values, for starters: getMemebers != getMembers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I addition to Shawn's comment, I believe you'll have a problem with starting your array index at 0, rather than 1.  Coldfusion begins array indices at 1.

*edit* Some more suggestions:

```
<cfset dataArray = []>
 <cfloop query="getMembers">
        <!--- Not usually a good idea to query each time through a loop - should be able to do a single query outside it --->
        <cfquery name="getmaps" datasource=“a" dbtype="odbc">
        SELECT       member_id, mlong, mlat
        FROM         maps 
        WHERE       member_id = <cfqueryparam value='#getMembers.MemberID#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"><!--- assuming varchar since you had quotes around it --->
        </cfquery>
        <cfif getmaps.recordcount eq 1>
            <!--- temp structure to insert into array --->
            <cfset dataTemp = {
                memberID = getMembers.memberID, 
                name = getMembers.MemberName, 
                long = getmaps.mlong, 
                lat = getmaps.mlat 
            }>
            <cfset ArrayAppend(dataArray,dataTemp)>
        </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I should point out that in my example, I removed the `i` variable completely, instead opting for the built-in CF Array manipulation function ArrayAppend.  That way you have one less variable to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider combining the two queries into one query.

```
<cfquery name="qryMemberMaps" datasource="a" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT
    members.memberID, members.MemberName,
    maps.mlong, maps.mlat
FROM
    [members_database].dbo.members JOIN [maps_database].dbo.maps ON members.memberID = maps.member_id
</cfquery>
```

The current method could potentially generate thousands of queries when you only need one!

Anytime you find yourself looping over a query and calling other queries, it is a good idea to revise the original query and save hammering your database server.

For putting the data into an array of structs, Jake's answer works well.

Comment: the maps table is in a separate database sadly, can I join across databases in CF? I’ve tried before and only gotten errors.

Comment: Typically, yes. Assuming the datasource account has permissions to *both* databases.

Comment: I know for certain that you can if the databases are both Microsoft SQL Server. You would have to fully qualify the database tables in the FROM clause.  I updated the query above to include an example of fully qualified database tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining multiple DB's make sure that you create a non-clustered index on the column(s) that will act as the primary/foreign keys.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you mean by non-clustered index could you show me an example maybe?